# wp_mail not sending in test php file

Tags: wp-mail

I created a test php file which exists in public_html.
I also copied it to the wp-content folder.

All it does is call:

```
<?php 

wp_mail('myemail@mydomain.com','test','hi');

?>
```

Neither file actually sends the email when I load it in the browser.

What am I doing wrong??? I read the codex and from what I can see, nothing else is required as arguments.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test.php file is a standalone script and isn't part f WordPress so it has no access to the WordPress functions.

A simple way to resolve this would be to include **wp-load.php** at the top of your script, but **AFAIK** this is not a good approach as you're loading WordPress over again to use just a single function.

In your public_html folder

```
<?php 

require_once('wp-load.php');

wp_mail('myemail@mydomain.com','test','hi');

?>
```